# Reset the root password in mysql in Ubuntu 18.04 OS

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

ok here's the thing I tried installing MySQL-server and it did install perfectly no problem there. 
later I had had to format my system and then when I tried to install it, it did install but it did not prompt for the root password. when I later tried to reset the root password here's the problem I get

```
    user@user:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
    [ ok ] Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
    user@user:~$ sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
    [3] 13831
    user@user:~$ mysql -u root -p
    ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
    [3]   Exit 1                  sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

I tried resolving the 2002 error but I am unable to do so. any help will be appreciated.

from what I understand I should not get the 2002 error to proceed further

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably due to error in installation. Try the following:

Ensure that my MySQL service is running by executing the following command in the terminal:

```
$ sudo service mysql start
```

Verify the state of the process:

```
$ ps -A|grep mysql
$ ps -A|grep mysqld
```

Then kill the process with the following command:

```
$ sudo pkill mysql
$ sudo pkill mysqld
```

Finally restart the service:

```
$ sudo service mysql restart
```

And run the following command:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: Umm.. I did manage to remove. "[3] exit 1 "    from the ERROR 2002. but still it wont go further to reset the root password

Comment: Yes it is the same

Comment: @usr have you tried uninstalling and installing mysql again?

Comment: I guess this is the 7 time i tried uninstalling and installing it again.  I dont know if this is of any help too but here it is.  The xampp server wont start the apache server.

Comment: @usr Does it not ask you to set the password again when you reinstall?

Comment: No it dosent ask me to set the password again.

Comment: @usr Could you try a complete uninstall using the command `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common` followed by `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql`. After which you can install it again and allow you to reconfigure it.

Answer (score 0):

**Step#1**: Run this command:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

**Step#2**: press `n`

**Step#3**: input your password.

**Step#4**: press y for until it says All done!

[or follow this video tutorial](https://youtu.be/6d5RREqxN44)

Also to change the password use this command:

mysql> `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_password';`